# qpainter painting alternatives (performance sucks on Mac)

Tags: c++, performance, qt, macos, paint

I have a class which displays waveform data of audiofiles in a QWidget (see screenshot of the widget below, back then i still used a gradient, which caused poor performance).

The audio data is painted in the paintEvent directly on the widget using multiple calls to `QPainter::drawLine` (the minimum amount of calls to `QWidget::drawLine` is equivalent to the width of the widget => at least one line for each x coordinate).
While the approach works quite well on Windows (a paintEvent in fullscreen takes around ~4ms), the performance is 4-5 times worse when the program is run under MacOS.

The performance of the painting is important for fluid scrolling of the displayed data.

So my question is, does anyone know a faster alternative to QPainter.drawLine to paint lines (platform dependant solutions might be ok, as long as they can be used in a paintEvent), or is there a way to speed up scrolling, some kind of buffering etc ?

[image: old screenshot of the widget (still used gradients, which caused poor performance)]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current version (4.7.x) of Qt uses Core Graphics backend for painting. It can be slow at times as you found out. On Windows, it uses a software renderer which has really good performances.

My suggestion is to not paint on the passed painter directly in your paint event. Instead, create a `QImage` the same size as your widget paint area and paint on it. This will use the software renderer which is much faster. Then plot the `QImage` onto the painter when needed.

Comment: we are using qt 4.4, ive already tried painting the data on a QPixmap first, and then painting the pixmap onto the widget, but the speedup was marginal (QPainter::drawLine was not noticeably faster when painting on a pixmap)

Comment: I remember QPixmap is different from QImage in that QPixmap uses platform "accelerated" back end. In OS X that means it's still Core Graphics. Using QImage will ensure you are using the software renderer.

Comment: @smerlin QPixmap is optimized for showing images on screen, while QImage is optimized for I/O.  If you use QPixmap to draw the lines, then it will be slower.

Comment: using QImage with `QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied` resulted in really good performance ;)

Answer (score 4):

Use OpenGL and [QGLWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qglwidget.html) if you want to draw really fast.

Comment: simply deriving from `QGLWidget` instead of `QWidget` did not work, since lots of paint events simply were not routed to the widget, additionally the application just crashes on MacOS with an error message reading: "Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice", while i obviously already have an QApplication instance.

Comment: Additionally i doubt that just switching to OpenGL wont speed up anything since the data i paint changes every frame, and this data still has to be uploaded to the graphics card pretty much every frame ?!

Comment: If you use QGLWidget, you need to draw the image using the OpenGL API. It's quite easy to draw simple polyline like in your picture. And yes, when your data changes every frame, the data is moved every frame to the graphics card's memory, but the amount of data in your case should be so small, that it wont be a problem. And the actual drawing will be very fast.

Comment: qt documentation says that painting 2D data with QGLWidget still should be done with QPainter.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Although I think the documentation says that it is possible to use QPainter, not that it should be used. I have not used QPainter with QGLWidget so I don't know what kind of performance difference there is between using QPainter or OpenGL API.

Answer (score 0):

You could construct a QPainterPath and paint that instead of calling the drawLine function repeatedly. And also, you could cache the path, so it would be much faster after the first paint.